# Thread safety of google/dense_hash_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, hashmap

Are reading operations in the [`dense_hash_map`](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html) thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `const` C++ object of reentrant type (most are) is generally assumed to be thread-safe.

The documentation of `dense_hash_map` doesn't specify anything regarding thread-safety, so the most defensive approach would be to assume it isn't even reentrant. It takes unprotected global mutable state to make a class non-reentrant, though, and it's hard to find an argument for `dense_hash_map` to require that, but seeing as it stores its contents to disk, that might be all you can hope for. To assume the thing is thread-safe even on mutable operations is far-fetched without confirmation from the documentation.

Barring documentation, you might want to have a look at the implementation to see whether you can verify reentrancy for at least some subset of the API.

Answer (score 0):

According to the paper [Scalable, High Performance Ethernet Forwarding with CUCKOOSWITCH](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./dongz/papers/cuckooswitch.pdf) (2013), `google::dense_hash_map` is **not thread-safe** for reads and writes:

> [...] We therefore also compare to three non-thread-safe hash tables: the STL’s `hash_map` and Google’s `sparse_hash_map` and `dense_hash_map`. [...] These non-thread-safe tables do not support concurrent reads and writes.

I could not find any other information about `google::dense_hash_map` being thread-safe or not.